# dependency error while including org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient4.5.1

Tags: java, android, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

In my project, I am in need of including the org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient 4.5.1. While execution I am getting an error saying that, "httpclient:4.5.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by android". The screen shot is attached here. Please review it and tell me a solution. It would be a great help. Thanks in advance. The link for the screen shot is provided below.  [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_6AvL4zhJz-dlBvRmhoYUsxZHM/view?usp=sharing]

Answer (score 0):

Please use the lib org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client instead, add this in your pom.xml if you are using maven:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped</groupId><artifactId>org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client</artifactId>
<version>4.1.2</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP client is depreciated after API 22. If you are updated with support library 23 then you may get this error. 
[HTTP Client Deprecated](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client)

Use [HTTP URL Connection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) instead or you can use other third party library such as [RetroFit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) or [Volley](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley) with [OkHTTP](http://square.github.io/okhttp/).